# Define variable in single line command in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute a list of commands through the command:

```
bash -l -c "commands"
```

However, when I define a variable an then try to use them, the variable is undefined (empty). To be clear:

```
bash -l -c "var=MyVariable; echo $var"
```

Answer (score 10):

Bash expansion (as explained [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)) will expand the variable value inside the double quotes before actually executing the commands. To avoid so you can follow either of these options:

**Option 1:**

Avoid the expansion using single quotes

```
bash -l -c 'var=MyVariable; echo $var'
```

**Option 2:**

Avoid the expansion inside the double quotes by escaping the desired variables

```
bash -l -c "var=MyVariable; echo \$var"
```

The second option allows you to expand some variables and some others not. For example:

```
expandVar=MyVariable1
bash -l -c "var=MyVariable; echo $expandVar; echo \$var"
```

Answer (score 5):

Bash expands variables inside double quotes. So in effect in your command `$var` is replaced by the *current* value of `var` *before* the command is executed. What you want can be accomplished by using single quotes:

```
bash -l -c 'var=MyVariable; echo $var'
```

Please note that it is rather unusual to invoke Bash as a login shell (`-l`) when passing a command string with `-c`, but then you may have your reasons.